# How to find top 3 salaries in queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got 2 tables with data like this

| employee | id |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| D | 4 |
| B | 2 |

| id | salary |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1250 |
| 1 | 254 |
| 3 | 434 |
| 4 | 1200 |
| 1 | 124 |

how can I find top 3 salaries?

```
Select sum(salaries) from employees.table
left join salaries.table
on id = id 
order by salary desc limit 3
```

is that right approach?

Comment: Don't understand your first table, you best way is to share your sample data here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: It sounds like you want the top 3 employees, arranged by salary, which isn't quite the same thing

Comment: @Strawberry yeah, exactly! What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: So what's the thinking behind SUM() here?

Comment: i thought i could sum all salaries and then rank them. like group by employee

Comment: Just exactly how difficult would it have been to reproduce that tiny amount of data in the question instead of forcing people to click through to minuscule images to find out what you're trying to do? Help us to help you!

Comment: So using `sum` as you have done will do exactly as instructed and will sum the value over all rows and present you with single total value. You need to group the sums by something - you just said it in your last comment.

Comment: Instead of image please add sample data in text format.

Comment: Why does the employee table have duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the group by clause and you need to use `sum(salary)` in order by clause since you are ordering employees on their sum of salaries after grouping them by employee.

```
Select employee,sum(salary) from employees.table e
left join salaries.table s
on e.id = s.id 
group by employee
order by sum(salary) desc limit 3
```

DB-Fiddle:

```
 create table Employee_table (employee varchar(50),id int);
 insert into Employee_table values ('A',1);
 insert into Employee_table values ('A',1);
 insert into Employee_table values ('B',2);
 insert into Employee_table values ('D',4);
 insert into Employee_table values ('B',2);
      
 create table Salary_table (id int, salary int);
 insert into Salary_table  values (1,1250);
 insert into Salary_table  values (1,254);
 insert into Salary_table  values (3,434);
 insert into Salary_table  values (4,1200);
 insert into Salary_table  values (1,124);
```

Query:

```
 Select employee,coalesce(sum(salary),0) Salary from Employee_table e
 left join Salary_table s
 on e.id = s.id 
 group by employee
 order by sum(salary) desc limit 3
```

Output:

| employee | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3256 |
| D | 1200 |
| B | 0 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4382901645ad90a471930f4ea99f68d0)*

Answer (score 0):

Your employee table has duplicates, which looks very problematic.  I would suggest that you just use the `salaries`:

```
select sum(salary)
from salaries s
group by id
order by sum(salary) desc
limit 3 ;
```

If you are going to use the first table for *anything*, you need to understand why there are duplicates, so you can figure out the best way to handle them.